# Programmatically take X amount of pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to implement a feature of taking X amount of pictures programmatically after entering a `UIViewController` for both the iPhone and iPad. I looked into `UIImagePickerController` but I do not want to present the camera controls and have the user hit a button to capture only one photo. Is there a way to capture X amount of photos once entering a `UIViewController` and storing all the photos in the end for future reference in one go?

### **Edit**:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Create image picker controller
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }
    else
    {
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }

    // Set source to the camera
    picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Delegate is self
    picker.delegate = self;

    // Allow editing of image ?
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    //picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    // Show image picker
    [picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question to show some code from your view controller that shows how you are programmatically taking a picture?

Comment: I am asking if there is another way to take pictures programmatically.  I have edited the question with my current code that uses the UIImagePickerController but does not accomplish what I want it to.

Comment: you should look at AVCaptureSession may be that can help you

Comment: Is there a tutorial that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

straight away with takePicture you can not take multiple snaps, for that you have to use some video recording and get snap out of it for particular frame or time, for you more reference you can use this apple documentation for bulk snaps [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
int numberOfPhotos = 3; // Number of photos you want to take.
for ( int i = 0; i < numberOhPhotos; i++ )
{
    // Note that you should use some sort of a pause in between each photo.
    [picker takePicture];
}
```

Comment: Is there a method that happens after takePicture is called? I would like to process the pictures taken and store them. Also, what is the best way to pause in between each photo?

Comment: Yes, `UIImagePickers` delegate `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is called after each **`takePicker`** call. As for pausing, you can set up `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. I would also look into `dispatch_after` queues, but they don't play too well with for loops.

Comment: I have in the same file, -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 NSLog(@"test");
}
The text, "test" is never displayed to console at all. Is there a reason why it's not called?

Comment: It appears that I need the picker to be presented. Is there a way to take pictures without presenting the PickerController?